# django_registration or django_registration_redux

Tags: python, django, registration, django-registration

I want to write a Django(1.9) application where users can register. After registration users should get an email with confirmation link. Because I don't want to write a boilerplate code I decided to look for something similar. I've found two solutions: [django-registration](https://django-registration.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.4/index.html) and [django-registration-redux](https://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). Both applications seem to be similar and I don't know which one I should use. Please, let me know which advantages/disadvantages they have or what is the best way to implement such functionality.

Comment: this doesn't really answer your question, but there are even more packages to consider! https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/registration/ - if you are considering using oauth (social logins) look at other packages.

Comment: @luke_aus your answer helps me a lot, because on that table there are preferences of other people. And there are much more votes for django-registration than for django-registration-redux.

Comment: I believe django-registration-redux was a fork off django-registration because django-registation was for a while incompatible with django 1.7 or django 1.8 - looks like django-registation activity has picked up again. So because django-registation-redux isn't as old, it probably wouldn't have as many votes.